# Problems with Capistrano's deploy:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm getting the following error while trying to deploy:migrate with Capistrano:

```
[err :: 127.0.0.1 ] /home/synapse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:388:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Before that I was getting rake not found' error but it was gone after I added "set :rake" to deploy.rb. Ruby is installed via RVM and rake gem is of course installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for capistrano you need to add extensions for rvm

```
set :rvm_ruby, "ruby-1.9.2-p180"
set :rvm_gem_home, "#{fetch(:base_dir)}/.rvm/gems/#{fetch(:rvm_ruby)}"
set :rvm_ruby_path, "#{fetch(:base_dir)}/.rvm/rubies/#{fetch(:rvm_ruby)}"
set :default_environment, {
  'RUBY_VERSION' => fetch(:rvm_ruby),
  'GEM_HOME' => "#{fetch(:rvm_gem_home)}:#{fetch(:rvm_gem_home)}@global",
  'BUNDLE_PATH' => fetch(:rvm_gem_home),
  'PATH' => "#{fetch(:rvm_gem_home)}/bin:#{fetch(:rvm_gem_home)}@global/bin:#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_path)}/bin:/home/rails/.rvm/bin:$PATH;",
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, helped me fix a similar can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) problem. Thanks!

Comment: Getting a "Capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:82:in `block in fetch': `base_dir' not found (IndexError)". Any ideas?